# How to get the revision history between particular time frame or after a certain revision or commit id upto the latest using Mercurial API?

Tags: mercurial, logging, dvcs, mercurial-hook

I want to fetch all the commits with their changeset after a particular commit id or time. Is there any straight way to do that using Mercurial API?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, there's [no stable Python-level API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi) for Mercurial. The command line is really the only supported API (unless you use a wrapper library like [JavaHg](http://javahg.org/) or [python-hglib](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PythonHglib)).

So on the command line you would run

```
$ hg log -r "ID::"
```

to get all changesets after `ID`. The `::` operator gives you descendents, use `ID:` if you simply want changesets with a higher revision number, even if they're not a descendent of `ID`.

Using JavaHg, you would instantiate a `Repository` object and use [`LogCommand`](http://javahg.aragost.com/apidocs/com/aragost/javahg/commands/LogCommand.html):

```
List<Changeset> changesets = LogCommand.on(repo).rev(id + "::").execute();
```

You can then iterate through the `changesets` list. With python-hglib it looks like

```
changesets = client.log(id + "::")
```

Finally, if you import the Mercurial code directly you can do

```
ctxs = repo.set(id + "::")
```

to get an iterator yielding [`changectx`](http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/mercurial/context.py) objects. While we give no guarantees about the Python API, I would expect this to be very stable too.

The above focused on looking up by a changeset ID or revision number. If you want to lookup by date, then you'll need to call the equivalent of

```
$ hg log -d '>YOUR-DATE'
```

In JavaHg you can just use the `date(String date)` method on `LogCommand`, in python-hglib you set the `date` keyword argument, and internally you use the `date` revset predicate — see [`hg help revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets).